# nav items getting stacked in elementor custom header template

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have made a custom header for my site and while it is in edit mode (editing with elementor) it  [looks like this](https://ibb.co/KWBBF0q). But after adding all the conditions and saving it when I see it in my pages it [looks like this](https://ibb.co/5hZtbQQ). I've rechecked every configurations but this remains the same.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing fine!

The issue most often happens due to enabling one of the Experimental Features of Elementor which is **Improved CSS Loading**. Kindly check [this screenshot](https://d.pr/i/D6euUw) and try deactivating that experimental feature. Hopefully, that will solve the issue.

Comment: the issue was solved after I had downgraded the elementor version...but will definitely try your solution..thanks

Comment: Sure. Please try with the updated version of the plugin. I hope your issue will be solved.